# Association Model Confusion in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models

```
User
Event
Group
```

All of them has one location. How can I associate above 3 with Location.
Should I create different Location table ?
What should be the best association mode ?

As each location can have multiple events, groups or users, I want to ensure uniqueness of Location.

Also I want one location for multiple models, for example - if there will be 5 users ad 5 events from new york , i want only 1 newyork created in my location table

Comment: Each of those models should `belongs_to :location` but if you're asking about uniqueness (as in "Apple Store, 5th Avenue, NYC, NY, USA") this is a task for you to make sure users reuse the location that is already in the db, Rails is not going to provide that for you

Comment: @MichalSzyndel That was confusing me whether rails take care uniqueness or not .

Comment: It can take care of uniqueness but understood literally, like comparing strings. What you're talking about in here is business logic and this part is what you have to take care of.

Comment: How I solved this in my application is by having an autocomplete/autosuggest/typeahead plugin on input field where I let the user to pick a desired location so they don't have to type all this information by hand. This way I can _help_ with keeping uniqueness but obviously user can do what they want.

Comment: Another solution would be to normalise addresses (take a look at geocoder gem) and then try to merge locations that seem to be the same + update ids in associated objects.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel m already using geocoder and geocomplete . i will use both solutions. i think i found solution thanks .

Comment: Well, that's good. Unfortunately those are the best solutions you're left with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a pre-defined set of locations (EG `New York`), you could put them into their own model:

```
#app/models/location.rb
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
   has_many :events
   has_many :groups

   validates :x, uniqueness: true
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :location
end

#app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :location
end

#app/models/group.rb
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :location
end
```

The above will allow you to call the following:

```
@location = Location.create({name: "New York"})

@event = Event.create({location: @location})
@group = Group.create({location: @location})
@user = User.create({location: @location})
```

--

> Also I want one location for multiple models

This is standard practice for [ActiveRecord associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association):

[image]

You'll be able to add a [`uniquness` validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness) into your `Location` model to make sure each record is saved independently.